# Bound on directional derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm stuck on the following problem in my preparation for an upcoming exam:

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is known that the directional derivatives satisfy $D_\textbf{u} f(0,0)<\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2$ for all $\textbf{u}\neq \textbf{i}$. Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$.

I would just appreciate a hint that can help me solve the problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: Recall that $$D_{\mathbf u} f(0,0) = \nabla f(0,0) \cdot \mathbf u = |\nabla f(0,0)| \cos \theta,$$ if $\mathbf u$ is a unit vector and $\theta$ is the angle formed by gradient and $\mathbf u$. The maximum therefore is reached on the direction of the gradient.

Comment: Remember, too, that $\partial f/\partial x$ is itself a directional derivative.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Much appreciated